# Using getrusage

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, process, gnu

As a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343034/time-cpu-used-by-process) I'm wondering if I can get some simple sample code as to how to [make use of getrusage](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_447.html). I would like to use it to find the **time CPU used by a process**, ideally from the **PID**.

I'm working in Cocoa, Objective_C and of course C. Any help would be awesome!

Thanks

Comment: @R.., Thanks, but I'm not sure how I misused the word. Explanation?

Comment: Eric Brotto: “Implement” would mean writing getrusage yourself, not calling the one that already exists.

Comment: *Implementing* `getrusage` is something you do if you're writing an operating system and you need to provide that interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out how to implement getrusage using help from [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getrusage.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469495/unix-programming-struct-timeval-how-to-print-it-c-programming). The unfortunate thing is that this manages to get information only about the current process. What I need is CPU time from all the processes running and this from their PID.

Bummer :(

Comment: Are you actually interested in the CPU usage of every process separately, or do you only care about CPU usage of the whole system overall?

Comment: @Peter I'm interested in the former: "the CPU usage of every process separately" as seen when you call top from command line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about OS X, but for what it's worth, if this were on Linux it would be a fairly simple matter of reading from a file underneath `/proc/<pid>`.  OS X doesn't seem to have `procfs` (at least, not standard), though, so this answer will fall into the "any help" category.  :)

Comment: Could you expand on that? Maybe point me in a direction of how exactly I would do what you are saying?

Comment: Eric Brotto: On a Linux-based OS, every process is represented by a file, named for the process's PID, on the /proc file system. On Mac OS X, there is no /proc file system (not built in, anyway—I think there's a third-party one available).